# Getting "Policy alternatives can not be satisfied" from cxf enpoint

Tags: kotlin, apache-camel, wsdl, cxf

I created a web service with cxf and camel from wsdl. Below are my bean configs:

```
@Bean
open fun cxfServlet(): ServletRegistrationBean<CXFServlet> {
    val servlet = ServletRegistrationBean(CXFServlet(), "/ws/*")
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1)
    servlet.setName("cxfServlet")
    return servlet
}

@Bean
open fun cxf(): Bus {
    return BusFactory.newInstance().createBus()
}

@Bean("endpoint")
open fun endpoint(bus: Bus): CxfEndpoint {
    val endpoint = CxfEndpoint()
    endpoint.address = "/endpoint"
    endpoint.serviceClass = IWebService::class.java
    endpoint.wsdlURL = "wsdl/mywsdl.wsdl"
    endpoint.dataFormat = DataFormat.POJO
    endpoint.bindingId = SOAPBinding.SOAP11HTTP_BINDING
    endpoint.isLoggingFeatureEnabled = true
    endpoint.loggingSizeLimit = -1
    return endpoint
}
```

Also I configured ssl. I use springBoot and my properties file is:

> server.port=8442
>   security.require-ssl=true
>   server.ssl.key-store-type=PKCS12
>   server.ssl.key-store=classpath:keystore.p12
>   server.ssl.key-store-password=123456
>   server.ssl.key-alias=testalias

Service's wsdl is available at the address:

> https://localhost:8442/ws/endpoint?wsdl

It worked fine until the moment I used WSDl with block "Policy":

```
<wsp:Policy wsu:Id="id">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
        <wsp:All>
            <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
                <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:TransportToken>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false"/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:TransportToken>
                    <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic256/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                    <sp:Layout>
                        <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Strict/>
                        </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Layout>
                </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportBinding>
        </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
</wsp:Policy>
```

And now the app runs correct, but when I send message an exception appears:

> org.apache.cxf.ws.policy.PolicyException: These policy alternatives can not be satisfied: 
>   {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}TransportToken
>   {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}HttpsToken
>   {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}AlgorithmSuite
>   {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}Basic256
>   {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}Layout
>   {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy}Strict

But if I create server in soapUI it works fine.
I tried some advices about creating interceptors and other from stackoverflow but nothing changed. 
How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Webservice secured with SSL? The error complains that the **declared security policy in the WSDL is not fulfilled.**

> Notice that the WSDL policy assertions **do not set up** the HTTPS transport between the requestor and provider! They **ensure only that the declared mechanisms are in place** when the web service with the defined policy is called.

And for SoapUI I don't really know but I assume that it ignores the policy.

Comment: Yes, I configured ssl. But the error remained anyway. I completed the question.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found some kind of solution with using of **IgnorablePolicyInterceptorProvider**. But this is just ignoring the policies, as far as I understand it, and I don't think this is a real solution:

```
val reg = bus.getExtension(PolicyInterceptorProviderRegistry::class.java)
val set = HashSet<QName>()
set.add(QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy", "TransportBinding"))
set.add(QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy", "TransportToken"))
set.add(QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy", "HttpsToken"))
set.add(QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy", "AlgorithmSuite"))
set.add(QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy", "Basic256"))
set.add(QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy", "Layout"))
set.add(QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy", "Strict"))
reg.register(IgnorablePolicyInterceptorProvider(set))
```